# Bit patterns expressed in hexadecimal notation

Tags: unsigned, bit, hex, twos-complement

Ok. So I've been presented with a problem that says there is a bit pattern expressed in hex notation. The first is 0x0C000000 . The thing is, I'm supposed to assume it's a two's complement integer and then unsigned integer. After assuming that, I am supposed to say what the decimal number is based on it being two's complement and unsigned.

Should I just convert from hex to 2's complement? How do I do that without first converting to decimal?

Any other possible insight would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

By your description, I understand that you have to write out two possibilities for what value could be represented.  One for a signed integer with two's compliment representation, and one for an unsigned integer.

So the first thing you do is to convert the number to binary, and look at the bits.

For the signed integer, you decide whether it's negative at all.  If it is, you use the two's compliment transformation to negate it (make it positive) and make sure you remember to write a minus sign.

Then, in either case, you do a decimal conversion of the binary number and write the resulting number out.